# How long am I able to use SharePoint 2010 beta?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, beta

How long am I able to use SharePoint 2010 beta version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But remember it's only a beta and you wont ever get any updates for it.

Comment: But, if I pay for the product afterwards, will I be able to upgrade to RTM or it's now known?

Comment: There no update path from beta to RTM as I know !

Comment: Ok, i see this is confirmed by MVP and MSFT users: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/b9817862-fd35-413a-b018-ce5c500b6760

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any limitations of length of time.